# modeling heat transfer in a non-hollow cylinder starting at r=0

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, boundary-conditions, thermal-conductivity

I have 2 questions about the heat equation in a cylinder that involve the behaviour at $r=0$ and the boundary conditions. But first a little more context:

I want to model a reaction in a cylindrical domain. The reaction is heavily dependant on heat transfer so before doing anything else I want to make sure the heat transfer model works fine. I'm using the Finite Element Method (FEM) and programmed it in Wolfram's Mathematica. Here's a picture ilustrating the domain:

[image]

I'm at the point where my FEM code works and I get a solution that looks the way I'd expect it. However I realized that the solution is heavily dependent on how fine the mesh is close to $r=0$

I used the standard (stationary) heat equation for cylindrical coordiantes as my governing equation and independent of the rotational direction:
$$
-\cfrac{1}{r} \cfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(a_{rr}r\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)
-\cfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(a_{zz}\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right)
-f(r,z)=0
$$

through FEM the Problem becomes a linear system of equations (that represents a mesh) that can be solved:

$$
[K] \cdot u = f + q
$$

$[K]$ is the so called stiffness matrix, $u$ is the vector with the nodal temperatures, $f$ is heat generation, $q$ is heat flow.

I modeled a cylinder with $r=0.1\space m,\space h=z=0.4\space m$ (since the problem is axisymmetric I only need to model a "slice" of the cylinder from 0 to r and 0 to z). To test it, I chose the BCs to be 50 on the inner boundary ($r=0,\space 0<z<0.4$) and 25 on the outside boundaries. This is the point where I suspect my mistake may lie.

Here's an example with the (nodal) solution. There's also a outside wall of the cylinder that is being modeled. it has a thickness of 0.02 and is on the bottom and the side of the cylinder (it is somewhat visible, since the mesh of the wall is coarse). The underlying mesh very close to $r=0$ to be more precise $0<r<0.005$ is refined. In the Orange solution that refinement, which means the area of the elements, is one order of magnitude larger than in the blue one (orange refined mesh is coarse, blue one is fine). Aside of the refined strip, the mesh element areas in both solutions are similar. The curves look very similar at first:

[image]

In a magnified version close to $r=0$ however it is apparent that the orange solution is slightly above the blue one.

[image]

Here's a cross section that emphasizes this further.

[image]

Every further refinement has the same effect, the starting trajectory close to $r=0$ becomes steeper with that having an effect on the rest of the solution in r-direction.

Is this behaviour close to $r=0$ to be expected?

I assume it has something to do with the BCs I gave:

I should probably enforce $q$ to be $0$ at $r=0$ since thats the symmetric condition. If I do that, can I still asign a constant temperature to that same boundary or would that make the system overdetermined?

If I assume that outside of the described domain there is air at room temperature (let's say 25°C) is it correct to assign 25°C to the outside borders of the cylinder or should I use a convection boundary?

Comment: You should have q = 0 at r = 0.  Otherwise it will be overdetermined.  And you should be solving for T at r = 0 using the same PDE, but with an appropriate treatment of the boundary condition.  Regarding the outer boundary condition, you should have a heat transfer coefficient to the room air on the outside of the tube.